# Number DatagramPackets

Tags: java, networking, udp, datagram

I have an artificially made network (homework) that I think makes the `packets out of order`, I'm not completely certain as there's also frequent packet loss in short bursts.

So I was wondering if it's possible to determine or number `DatagramPacket`s on the sender side so the receiver could check whether they're in order or not.

Comment: Of course, just put a sequence number into the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP packets don't have a sequence number. UDP segments don't have a sequence number. TCP segments do have a sequence number, but out-of-order segments are handled automatically by TCP.

If you are using UDP, you will need to create your own datagram type as the UDP payload, and you can include a sequence number in your datagram. For instance, RTP, typically carried in UDP segments, has a sequence number.

Comment: As I've stated before it's homework so I can't make any changes to the network as the datagrampackets are custom made by my professor. Also I'm not sure if they're actually out of order, just want to make sure before I dig in.

Comment: Ah, nevermind the sockets are custom made not the packets. I might just create one with an extra field to set the sequence. Thanks for the tip.